# How can I predict this Rf model correctly

Tags: r, caret

Used a Random Forest classifier for some data, using this command. The (Type) field is 0 and 1 with some NA hence the NA action

```
Websites <- read.csv("malicious_and_benign_websites12.csv")
datasplit = sort(sample(nrow(Websites), nrow(Websites)*.8))
train<-Websites[datasplit,]
test<-Websites[-datasplit,]

install.packages("caret") 
library(caret)
RF_model <- train(as.factor(Type) ~ .,
             data = train
             method = 'ranger'
             na.action = na.exclude
            )
  RF_model
```

This all worked after some time training but then I needed to predict the model and construct a confusion matrix using this command.

```
  datasplitRFPred <- predict(RF_model, test)
  confusionMatrix(datasplitRFPred, as.factor(test$Type)
```

Thats when trouble arose when I got this error

```
> datasplitRFPred <- predict(RF_model, test)
      Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = 
   object$xlevels) : 
          factor URL has new levels B0_10, B0_101, B0_1016, B0_1019, B0_1028, B0_1057, B0_1088, B0_1093, B0_1102, B0_1113, B0_1146, B0_1160, B0_1161, B0_120, B0_1206, B0_1211, B0_123, B0_1233, B0_1257, B0_126, B0_1260, B0_1279, B0_1296, B0_1300, B0_1302, B0_1304, B0_1317, B0_1330, B0_1340, B0_1347, B0_1366, B0_1369, B0_1378, B0_1386, B0_1387, B0_1392, B0_1394, B0_1403, B0_1404, B0_1410, B0_1412, B0_1419, B0_157, B0_158, B0_168, B0_181, B0_2011, B0_2024, B0_203, B0_2051, B0_206, B0_207, B0_2072, B0_2075, B0_2077, B0_2111, B0_2112, B0_2116, B0_2119, B0_2122, B0_2130, B0_2153, B0_2159, B0_216, B0_2168, B0_2169, B0_2221, B0_2228, B0_2235, B0_2236, B0_2241, B0_2273, B0_2282, B0_2287, B0_2309, B0_235, B0_237, B0_244, B0_254, B0_28, B0_281, B0_289, B0_296, B0_307, B0_312, B0_314, B0_331, B0_334, B0_335, B0_34, B0_341, B0_343, B0_348, B0_354, B0_36, B0_408, B0_421, B0_422, B0_429, B0_438, B0_444, B0_447, B0_46, B0_471, B0_497, B0_518, B0_529, B0_531, B0_533, B0_535, B0_536, B0_537, B0_554, B0_5
 confusionMatrix(datasplitRFPred, as.factor(test$Type)
```

anyway to fix this???

Cant make the matrix and get the performance metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert `Type` to a `factor` upfront within the `Website` dataset. You convert your training data within `train()` and the test data within the `confusionMatrix()` but then use the original train data in `predict()` without the factor conversion.